# htaccess - RewriteRule to another Domain and remove folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'am trying to redirect all incoming http-requests from one domain to another.

So in fact I have a directory with images, lets say *www.domain.com/**dir1**/images/image.png* . Now I want to redirect this calls to a new domain. The new domain looks like this: *www.newdomain.com/images/image.png*

This means, I need to remove the "**dir1**" folder from one url.

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir1/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R,L,NC]
```

But this doesn't work. It does not redirect my calls. Can somebody help me?